# pip installation fails for zlib library

Tags: python-2.7, pip, zlib

when I try to install zlib by below command

```
sudo pip install zlib
```

I am getting below error...

```
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement zlib
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for zlib
```

Comment: not surprising, as there is [no such library on pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zlib). Are you trying to install the zlib system library? If so, use your systems package manager, pip isn't the right tool for that.

Comment: then, why I am getting no module named zlib when I try to start django?

Comment: That means the `zlib` module from the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html) can't be imported, which may indicate problems with your python installation, so this is actually about something completely unrelated to pip. You should edit your question accordingly and add the full error message you're getting.

Comment: Are you sure zlib is not already compiled into your Python?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to `pip install zlib` as zlib is not a library on pypi.  If apt-get is an option, consider using

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```