# Pipenv can't find zlib module (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zlib')

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pipenv

As mentioned in title, when I try to install dependencies using `Pipenv install` I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zlib'`. although it seems to work outside of Pipenv, there is no issue installing same dependencies using pip3 outside of Pipenv shell. I am using m1 chip Mac, so I already tried reinstalling `Xcode-select --install`. also tried `brew reinstall zlib`. but no progress so far.

Answer (score 0):

there aren't any zlib packages in pypi https://pypi.org/search/?q=zlib

You can try with

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

**References:**

- [pip installation fails for zlib library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36496704/pip-installation-fails-for-zlib-library)
- [no module named zlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169522/no-module-named-zlib)